# How can I disable a form's submit button if there are DataAnnotation validation errors?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I've attempted binding to the change event of all inputs in the form, and checked to see if there are any validation messages on the page. The problem is that validation seems to occur after the change event, so I am checking before the errors appear on the page. I'm looking for some way to run my script after the client-side validation takes place.

I'm using MVC 2 with DataAnnotation attributes on my VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I just hacked together that wraps the original `parseElement` and `invalidHandler` functions, allowing you to add your own logic.

```
(function($) {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parseElement = (function (original) {
        return function (element, skipAttach) {
            original.call(this, element, skipAttach);
            var form = $(element).parents("form:first")[0];
            var validationInfo = $(form).data('unobtrusiveValidation');
            if (validationInfo) {
                var handler = validationInfo.options.invalidHandler;
                var newhandler = function () {
                    console.log('Here is where you can do additional handling');
                    handler.call(this);
                };
                validationInfo.options.invalidHandler = $.proxy(newhandler, form);
            } else {
                // this didn't work.
            }
        }
    })($.validator.unobtrusive.parseElement);
})(jQuery);
```

Notice, though, that this is an immediate function, not the jQuery function which is equivalent to document.onload.

This is *replacing* the `$.validator.unobtrusive.parseElement` with a new function that calls the original to ensure the `validationInfo.options.invalidHandler` is applied to the parent form, which then allows you to wrap that handler with the `newhandler` function.

**Edit:
The above answer will only work for MVC3 and unobtrusive validation.**

To perform some additional functionality with `$.validator` when the form is invalid...

```
$('form:first').bind("invalid-form.validate", function () { 
    alert("invalid!"); 
 });
```

Comment: I note the word "unobtrusive" in your code - I'm worried that your solution relies on unobtrusive JS support, which I understand is a part of MVC 3 but not 2. Is this the case?

Comment: @Will: I apologize. I read the last line in your post as MVC3 with the DataAnnotations attributes (HTML5, unobtrusive). I guess I should stay off SO on Monday mornings. I updated the answer with an example of binding functionality to invalid forms.  This way when a form is marked invalid, you can run your own scripts.  I hope this is closer to your question.

Comment: Not a problem. Does the code in your modified solution rely on any plugins? The callback seems to never be triggered for me. Thanks again!

Comment: @Will, sorry I didn't see your question before.  This does rely on the jquery.validate plugin, which is the default for MVC 2 RTM client-side validation. There is also a `MicrosoftMvcJqueryValidation.js` which handles ajax submits.  If you're using that instead of jquery.validate, I can track down the file and take a look.