# Highlight DisplayFor if not passed validation defined in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, umbraco

Is there any way to highlight/ style DisplayFor or/and DisplayNameFor fields depending on validation defined in the model?

It is in a strongly typed partial view and I'm using umbraco 7

```
@inherits  UmbracoViewPage<MyProject.Models.ImportViewModel>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Master.cshtml";
}    
<table class="list">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    var categories = (IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Category>)ViewData["categories"];

    <tr class="list-item">
        <td>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <h2>
                                (@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ref))
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                            </h2>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label class="auto">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item.Status)</label>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)<br /><br />

                            @Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", new { id = item.Id })
                        </td>
                    </tr>



                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Category:</label> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => categories.First(m => m.Id == item.CategoryId).Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item.Description)</label>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DescriptionShort)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I have this in my controller:

```
List<MyProject.Models.Import> items = (List<MyProject.Models.Import>)Session["sesimp"];
return PartialView("ItemList", new ImportViewModel { Items = items });
```

I want to highlight fields which are not correct based on the field validation defined in the model.

So for example if *category* is not selected and it is defined as required in model) then this field on the list has different css class assigned and/or possibly display error message. Same if *Ref* is empty, *Title* or *Description* contains invalid characters etc.

Also I need to disable *Approve* link if the item didn't pass validation.

How to do it?

Comment: Not clear why you would be allowing invalid models when creating or editing them but you could add additional properties to your view model and then validate each model in a loop e.g. `bool IsValid = TryValidateModel(yourModel);` and use the property to determine if the `Approve` link should be disabled

Comment: loki2302 solved a similar problem for adding a class when a specific field is invalid (which you could use for highlighting) see - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16448404/201648. Likewise, Jim Schubert wrote a jQuery handler which checks for invalid fields and allows you to apply some logic (such as disabling a button http://stackoverflow.com/a/7067346/201648. For enabling/disabling a button see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1594992/201648 (OR disabling a link http://stackoverflow.com/a/970413/201648)

Comment: Thank you @AaronNewton. I will try solutions you suggest.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I need to show records first so user see they need editing or not before processing them

Comment: Yes, but why would you allow invalid models when you first create them? Note @AaronNewton suggested links are not relevant because you don't have a form or inputs

Comment: Hmmm... Stephen is right. I was basing my answer on using unobtrusive validation on a form, e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/577937/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Validating-Model-Data-and. And YES, you should be checking _if (ModelState.IsValid)_ on postback of the original form. A possible scenario where I could see this happening is when data is created with one application not enforcing the validation logic, and then loaded into another which does. I suspect first approach might work, but I haven't tried it under these conditions stackoverflow.com/a/16448404/201648

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am importing the data from Excel spreadsheet to a session and performing malware validation on import. What I need to do then is to allow users to check the records are correct for the site and import them to the database.